# Moving key/value pair from one Hash to another

Tags: ruby, hash

I am a newbie programmer using Ruby, and this is my first question on Stack Overflow so please bear with me. Let's say I have two Hashes:

```
hash_one = { :key1 => :value1, :key2 => :value2, :key3 => :value3 } 
hash_two = { :key4 => :value4, :key5 => :value5, :key6 => :value6 }
```

What would be the easiest way to move a key/value pair from `hash_one` (e.g. `:key1 => :value1`) into `hash_two`?

Answer (score 5):

```
hash_two[:key1] = hash_one.delete(:key1)
```

`delete` removes `key1` from `hash_one` and returns the value of `key1`. That value is taken as the parameter to set this key in `hash_two`.

Comment: Good answer, tessi.  Wouldn't it be handy if we had two forms of each `delete`, the one we have, which is useful in situations like this, and a second that would return what's left of the object from which the item was deleted?  The latter would be useful if we knew an item would be deleted or didn't care if one were deleted or not.

Comment: @CarySwoveland [Hash#reject](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-reject) is only slightly cumbersome to use for that purpose.